# Is this regression problem solvable?

Tags: linear-programming, matrix-equations, linear-regression

I have a random vector $\pmb{x}=(X_1,...,X_p)^T\in \mathbb{R}^p$, a symmetric matrix
$$\Theta = \left(\begin{matrix}0 & \theta_{12} & \theta_{13} & \cdots & \theta_{1p}\\
\theta_{12} & 0 & \theta_{23} & \cdots & \theta_{2p}\\
\theta_{13} & \theta_{23} & 0 & \cdots & \theta_{3p}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & & \vdots \\
\theta_{1p} & \theta_{2p} & \theta_{3p} & \cdots & 0
\end{matrix} \right) \in \mathbb{R}^{p\times p},$$
and a random error vector $(\epsilon_1,...,\epsilon_p)^T\in \mathbb{R}^p$. In my setting, I have the following regression models

$$ \left(\begin{matrix}X_1\\X_2\\ \vdots\\X_p \end{matrix}\right) = \Theta\left(\begin{matrix}X_1\\X_2\\ \vdots\\X_p \end{matrix}\right) + \left(\begin{matrix}\epsilon_1\\\epsilon_2\\ \vdots\\\epsilon_p \end{matrix}\right)$$
My questions is: How to estimate $\Theta$ given data $\{\pmb{x}_i\}_{i=1}^n $ i.i.d from $\pmb{x}$ with $p<n$?

I tried to read about trace regression introduced in High-Dimensional Statistics: A Non-Asymptotic Viewpoint by Martin J. Wainwright, but I think my setting is different since the response vector and the predictor vector are the same. I guess this is related to matrix completion / compressed sensing, but I am not familiar with this literature and do not know where to start. Does anyone have suggestions?

My setting needs $p>n$, and I guess I can simply add some penalty term. Any literature I can have a look at?

Comment: If you choose to downvote this question, kindly provide a brief explanation so I can enhance it. Otherwise, it only diminishes my points and may discourage me from engaging further on this platform. While I acknowledge that my question may seem simplistic, silently dismissing it feels unwelcoming to a newcomer like myself.

Comment: "How to estimate $\Theta$" is not a math question.  The appropriately sized all-zero matrix is an estimate of $\Theta$.  So is any other appropriately sized matrix.  If you want an estimate with certain properties, you need to specify those properties.  We are not mindreaders.  (Also, the triple redundancy in your setup is the opposite of inviting.  I am editing.)

Comment: This might be a better place to discuss your question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: crossposted: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/639678/is-this-regression-problem-solvable

Comment: Please if you crosspost, say so. It is ok to post after waiting some time and not getting an answer, but at least provide a link.

Comment: While I'm not sure, this seems quite close to the learning with errors problem — you have a bunch of approximate linear identities on the variables $\theta$

Comment: @CommandMaster Yes, I think so. I think it is related to solving underdetermined linear systems. I will look into that.

Comment: @StevenLandsburg Thank you for the clarification. [Here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/467095/symmetric-linear-least-squares-solution-with-known-diagonal-elements) is my attempt to formulate it into a (hopefully?) math problem.

Comment: @mathoverflowUser While I understand that this question isn’t a great fit for MO, it’s not exactly helpful to encourage users to ask ambiguous questions on other sites. Steven Landsburg’s comment makes it clear that some essential information is missing.

Comment: @CommandMaster Yes, that's me. But there has not been much progress so far.